# Symfony VS CakePHP : which one is closest to PHP

Tags: php, frameworks

I'm mostly a Rails developer but sometimes, I have to code in PHP. Because stackoverflow.com *prefers questions that can be answered*, I'd like to have a idea which one of the two is closest to PHP?

Sometimes, I'm under the impression that CakePHP is a outdated copy of Rails that wants to look like Ruby but fails at it and thus leaving the best of PHP behind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there are loads of questions dealing with the php framework issue.
for example:

- [php-framework-decision-analysis-paralysis](https://web.archive.org/web/20081219171154/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249984/php-framework-decision-analysis-paralysis)
- [what-php-framework-would-you-choose-for-a-new-application-and-why](https://web.archive.org/web/20081218134615/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648/what-php-framework-would-you-choose-for-a-new-application-and-why)
- [which-php-framework-is-closest-to-ruby-on-rails-cakephp-codeigniter](https://web.archive.org/web/20081223150145/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/117406/which-php-framework-is-closest-to-ruby-on-rails-cakephp-codeigniter)

I don't think this question will bring anything new to light.
besides I think the framework of choice is more and more Zend Framework (IMHO).

How would you define closeness?

All frameworks are written in 100% PHP, non of them could be any closer to PHP. They are PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I like symfony because it doesn't have PHP4 compatibility as a business goal.  This lets the framework ditch some of the cruft and limitations of PHP4 and leverages the much stronger OOP in PHP5.

Comment: Have you noticed that the Symfony code base does not use the new PHP5/OOP Interface construct whatsoever (at least last I checked, late last year)?  How can you construct proper, "program to the interface", OO software, without using interfaces?

Comment: Yes, I noticed that.  I don't think it weakens my point, though.  Static methods, private data members, get/set hooks, not having to use the awful reference operator, etc - working with 5 is just better.  Yes, I would like it if they used interfaces, but it's not a bad product for the lack of them.

Comment: @George In a dynamically typed language, you don't need static interfaces to "program by contract".